# Insert timestamp into bigquery table using pandas

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I have a table in Google bigquery, where a column is set to datatype timestamp.

I have to insert data using to_gbq function of pandas.

If I set the datatype to string instead of timestamp the data is loaded into the table.

But I want the column to be timestamp datatype.

How can the column type of dataframe converted to timestamp compatible with Google bigquery.

Error

[image]

Table schema

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is stored as `int64` datatype, or `int`, so if you would like to format it in such a way, you can store cast your column to this datatype in pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df.COLUMN_OBJECT = df.COLUMN_OBJECT.astype(np.int64)
df.COLUMN_DATETIME = df.COLUMN_DATETIME.apply(lambda x: x.timestamp).astype(np.int64)
```

You can have the timestamp in seconds, ms, or ns.

Comment: how do I convert the column of existing dataframe??

Comment: Convert it from what, what is the data type originally?

Comment: One column has object as datatype and the other has datetime64[ns], I want both to be timestamp

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to convert them.

Comment: A bit on SO rules, you can't extend the scope of a question, you should ask another one. Always show code attempts, snippets, sample data, and error messages so that people can help you. SO is not a coding service where you expect people to write your code, it is a community where people can help and guide you through your attempted solution.

Comment: I updated the question with all the details you asked